# How to fix unzip and zip installation failure in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, zip

I have been trying to install zip and unzip using Linux terminal (Ubuntu 20.04), but I end up getting this error (image attached). What could be the reason for this?

I have tried to use these commands but I end up getting the same error,

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing & sudo apt-get zip uzip --fix-missing.
```

Error messages:

```
**Err:1** http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 unzip amd64 6.0-25ubuntu1
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused)
*Err:2* http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 zip amd64 3.0-11build1
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zip/zip_3.0-11build1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot for following problem

##### 1. Check Internet is Active or not.

- Check The connection using ping command

> example: ping 8.8.8.8

if this works fine then try to check the nameserver in the file `/etc/resolve.conf`
if 8.8.8.8 not found in resolve.conf then add following line in resolve.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

also check the default route of your internet. You can check so by `ip r`
command.

if it has the default route from the interface which is giving you internet then its fine
else add route by command `sudo ip r a default via <your gatway> dev <your-interface>`

> Example: sudo ip r a default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0

and then try to install the packages like zip and unzip.

##### 2. If all the above method didn't work, then it can be due to the reason of using proxy.

Example I am using proxy

```
m@m-Lenovo-ideapad-500-15ISK:~$ env | grep proxy
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
FTP_PROXY=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
https_proxy=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
http_proxy=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
ALL_PROXY=socks://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
all_proxy=socks://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
ftp_proxy=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
```

Now I can do `sudo -E apt-get update` to fix it as it will to pass on those environment variables to the elevated user.

OR

So I will append this in ~/.bashrc file

```
alias iiitproxy='export http_proxy="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080"; export https_proxy="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080";export ftp_proxy="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080"; echo "Acquire::http::proxy \"http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/\";" | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf'
```

then run the following in my terminal:

source ~/.bashrc
to refresh terminal and,

```
iiitproxy
```

This fixes my Issue if using proxy.

Comment: .....or maybe just try turning off ipv6